# How does Google Play autocomplete search suggestions work?

Tags: autocomplete

When searching on Google Play, there are autocomplete suggestions:

[image]

I always assumed that those are the most common searched terms.

However, some of the autocomplete suggestions are really unlikely to be common, for example:

[image]

Any ideas why would Google suggest such search terms?

Comment: This link may help you https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/106230?hl=en @Ronen

Comment: Thanks. I see that "The algorithm is based on a number of objective factors, including how often others have searched for a word." so I'm still confused about the long search suggestions. Any chance people are actually searching for "angry birds angry birds angry birds angry birds"? :)

Comment: yes, algorithm automatically detects and excludes a small set of search terms. but sorry No idea about that. And really it's Great question man :)

Comment: Try typing "yy" or "jx" I don't think autocomplete is based on what people search most