# How do I do a Text Input Suggestions Dropdown as part of a Form in Ionic?

Tags: ionic2

So I want to be able to do this common suggestion functionality in ionic 2:

[image: Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776328/how-does-google-play-autocomplete-search-suggestions-work]

Here is a starting point of reference.  Pretty basic.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form novalidate>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Location</ion-label>
      <ion-input required type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </form novalidate>
</ion-content padding>
```

1. I can rig the input to googles AutoComplete box. However, since I cannot force a selection in that provided box, I cannot work with it. So this is not an option in my case. Apart from that one problem, everything would work as expected.
2. I can't use a `SearchBar` here. It just donsn't fit into the form properly. I can't have a `Label` and a `SearchBar`.  The Searchbar just vanishes.
3. I can't put a `List` inside an `Item`. So I can't add a list under the `Input`.
4. I can revisit 3, but put the list under the `Item`. This isn't really what I want to do though. The `List` is connected to the `Input` Moving it outside just creates new problems with how the form behaves unless there is a way to make it float?

Does anyone have any alternative techniques that I could try? Am I missing something obvious here?